# How to make an alias for a folder on a mounted drive?

Tags: terminal, alias, .profile

I use parallels to run a windows machine and would love to make an alias in my .profile to make a shortcut to my project folder, but the following alias below dosn't seem to work.

```
alias trustpilot=/Volumes/C/Projects/stable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliases are for commands.
Like `alias trustpilot = 'cd /Volumes/C/Projects/stable'` lets you change to the directory by issuing the command `trustpilot`.
If you want to `cd $trustpilot` to your directory then you have to add it as a variable (without alias, just: `trustpilot = '/Volumes/C/Projects/stable'`) to your shell profile.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the alias to change directory to the wanted directory:

```
alias trustpilot="cd /Volumes/C/Projects/stable"
```

Now writing

```
trustpilot
```

will "cd" you to that directory.

---

If you want a symbolic link (a file that *points* to the directory in question) you can do

```
ln -s /Volumes/C/Projects/stable ~/trustpilot
```

This gives you a directory in your home that points to `/Volumes/C/Projects/stable`, so you can do e.g. `cd trustpilot` from your home to go there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making an alias to it:

`alias trustpilot='cd /Volumes/C/Projects/stable'`